# Lista de listas

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Preciso criar um mapa de caminhos, onde cada caminho aponta para outro e assim por diante. Estou usando ponteiro de ponteiro para uma lista, para que posso construir algo parecido com uma lista de adjacência, mas na hora de inserir os caminhos, algo da errado no segundo caminho e o programa para sem ao menos reportar algum erro.

jogo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Dlist.h"

#define TAMMAX 4 

Dlist** buildMap();

int main(){
    Dlist **MAP = buildMap();

    return 0;
}

Dlist** buildMap(){
    Dlist **ROAD = malloc(TAMMAX*sizeof(Dlist*));
    int i; char op;

    for(i=0; i<TAMMAX; ++i){ //erro está aqui quando i>0
        ROAD[i] = makeDlist();
        printf("Construa o caminho %d. Digite 0 para sair!\n", i+1);
        while(op = getchar(), op!='0'){
            fflush(stdin);
            insertDlist(ROAD[i], op);
        }
        printDlist(ROAD[i]);
    }

    return ROAD;
}
```

Dlist.h

```
#ifndef DLIST_H
#define DLIST_H

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct cell{
    char data;
    struct cell *next;
} CELL;

typedef struct Dlist{
    int size;
    CELL *head, *tail;
} Dlist;

Dlist* makeDlist();
void destroyDlist(Dlist* Dlist);
bool insertDlist(Dlist* Dlist, char DATA);
CELL* removeDlist(Dlist* list, int pos);
void printDlist(Dlist* Dlist);

#endif
```

Dlist.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Dlist.h"

Dlist* makeDlist(){
    Dlist* Dlist = malloc(sizeof(Dlist));

    Dlist->size = 0;
    Dlist->head = NULL;
    Dlist->tail = NULL;

    return Dlist;
}

void destroyDlist(Dlist* Dlist){
    if(Dlist == NULL){
        puts("LIST ALREADY DESTROYED!");
        return;
    }

    CELL *AUX = Dlist->head, *BYE; 
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<Dlist->size; ++i){
        BYE = AUX;
        AUX = AUX->next;
        free(BYE);
    }

    free(Dlist);

    return;
}

bool insertDlist(Dlist* Dlist, char DATA){
    if(Dlist == NULL){
        printf("INVALID LIST!");
        return false;
    }

    CELL* NODE = (CELL*)malloc(sizeof(CELL));

    if(!Dlist->size){
        Dlist->head = NODE;
        Dlist->tail = NODE;
        NODE->data = DATA;
        Dlist->size++;
        return true;
    }

    Dlist->tail->next = NODE;
    Dlist->tail = NODE;
    NODE->data = DATA;

    NODE->next = NULL;
    Dlist->size++;

    return true;
}

CELL* removeDlist(Dlist* Dlist, int pos){
    if(!Dlist->size){
        puts("EMPTY LIST!");
        return NULL;
    }

    CELL *REMOVED = malloc(sizeof(CELL));
    CELL *PREV, *CURRENT = Dlist->head;

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<pos-1;++i){
        PREV = CURRENT;
        CURRENT = CURRENT->next;
    }

    if(CURRENT == Dlist->head)
        Dlist->head = CURRENT->next;
    else
        PREV->next = CURRENT->next;

    REMOVED->data = CURRENT->data;
    free(CURRENT);
    Dlist->size--;

    return REMOVED;
}

void printDlist(Dlist* Dlist){
    CELL* AUX;
    int i;
    for(AUX=Dlist->head, i=1; AUX != NULL; AUX=AUX->next, i++){
        printf("%c->", AUX->data);
    }
    puts("END");
}
```

Comment: seu programa está bem organizado, mas apenas por inspeção visual acho que vai ser difícil achar o erro, pois trabalhar com listas e ponteiros é notoriamente é propenso a erros...sugiro você rodar em modo debug e seguir passo a passo a execução do programa

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se o programa faz o que deveria fazer, mas se tu substituir o nome da variável Dlist* Dlist por qualquer outro que não seja Dlist, o programa funciona. Em outras palavras, nunca use o nome da esrutura como nome de variável.